# How to fix violetion took 200ms when scrolling a block with message loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I load messages by 20 pieces, update the state when it reaches 0 on scroll and twist the block 20 messages back. But after a few scrolls, the page freezes and I get a warning in the console:
[Violation] 'message' handler took 187ms

I tried e.preventDefault() - didn't work, e.stopPropagation() - similar.
Please tell me what I did wrong?

```
onScroll={(e) => {
                    if(e.target.scrollTop < 1) {
                        const msgID = prevMessages.length ? parseInt(prevMessages[0].id) : parseInt(messages[0].id);
                        console.log(msgID);
                        socket.emit('getPrevMessages', {roomId, msgID});
                        e.target.scrollTo(0, e.target.querySelector('.direct-chat-msg:nth-child(20)').offsetTop);
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    }
                }}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You wrote code that takes too long to execute, and it blocked the browser from updating the screen during scrolling.  Write code that takes less time, or write it so that it is non-blocking (i.e. using `async`).

Comment: where is the code for this `'message' handler` that `took 187ms` - you haven't shown the code that produces the warning

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
function debounce(func, wait) {
  let timeout;
  return () => {
      if (timeout) {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
      }
      timeout = setTimeout(func, wait)
  }
}
const changeHandler = (e) => {
                  if(e.target.scrollTop < 1) {
                      const msgID = prevMessages.length ? parseInt(prevMessages[0].id) : parseInt(messages[0].id);
                      console.log(msgID);
                      socket.emit('getPrevMessages', {roomId, msgID});
                      e.target.scrollTo(0, e.target.querySelector('.direct-chat-msg:nth-child(20)').offsetTop);
                      e.stopPropagation();
                  }
              }
const debouncedChangeHandler = useCallback(
  debounce(changeHandler, 250)
, []);         
onScroll={ debouncedChangeHandler}
```

Comment: data not updated, i update question

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')
    at index.js:335:26
He can't get event

Comment: console.log(e) See what comes back

Comment: return undefined

Comment: Revised my answer

Comment: undefined event

Comment: `const debouncedChangeHandler = useCallback((e) => debounce(changeHandler(e), 250));`
I get event and func working, but i now get violation level warning

Answer (score 0):

The working but my handler not update states messages and prevMessages all time two empty arrays

```
const debounce = (func, wait) => {
        let timeout;
        return (() => {
            if (timeout) {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
            timeout = setTimeout(() => func(), wait)
        })();
    }

    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        if(e.target.scrollTop < 1) {
            const msgID = prevMessages.length ? parseInt(prevMessages[0].id) : parseInt(messages[0].id);
            console.log(msgID);
            socket.emit('getPrevMessages', {roomId, msgID});
            //e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
    const debouncedChangeHandler = useCallback((e) => debounce(() => changeHandler(e), 250),[]);
```